# Экспорт mysqli в csv php

Tags: php, mysqli, csv

Я экспортирует данные из базы данных и все работает почти корректно, но когда файл скачивается он добавляет и мусора к файлу.
Вот пример кода

```
function export_csv(){
  global $conn;
  $sql=$_SESSION['export'];
    $csv_export = '';
    $csv_filename="requests.csv";
    // query to get data from database
    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    $field = mysqli_field_count($conn);

    // create line with field names
    for($i = 0; $i < $field; $i++) {
        $csv_export.= mysqli_fetch_field_direct($query, $i)->name.',';
    }

    // newline (seems to work both on Linux & Windows servers)
    $csv_export.= '
    ';

    // loop through database query and fill export variable
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        // create line with field values
        for($i = 0; $i < $field; $i++) {
            $csv_export.= '"'.$row[mysqli_fetch_field_direct($query, $i)->name].'",';
        }
        $csv_export.= '
    ';
    }

    // Export the data and prompt a csv file for download
    header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$csv_filename."");
    echo($csv_export);
     exit;       }
```

Функцию я вызываю при нажатии на кнопку.
Вот исходные данные
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать все до 30 строки?

Comment: и что у вас никаких мыслей нет по поводу того, что тут происходит вообще?

Comment: это явно не весь код, в коде вывод в браузер, а показываете в экселе, вывод такой - до вывода csv-строк в браузер вы выводите хтмл-страницу

Comment: @Jean-Claude  в коде header content-disposition для загрузки файла

Comment: @teran смысл тот же, согласно https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition все что будет в выводе браузера, попадает на сохранение в файл. filename по спецификации в кавычках должен быть.

Comment: @Jean-Claude в предыдущем комментарии у вас были претензии к тому, что результат показывается в экселе.

Comment: @teran получается, это был риторический вопрос))

Answer (score 0):

Переписать функцию `export_csv()` следующим образом:

```
<?php
function export_csv() {
    global $conn;
    $sql=$_SESSION['export'];
    $csv_filename="requests.csv";
    // query to get data from database
    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    $field = mysqli_field_count($conn);
    // check count of fields
    if ($field > 0) {
        // create line with field names
        for($i = 0; $i < $field; $i++) {
            $csv_export = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($query, $i)->name.','.PHP_EOL;
        }

        // loop through database query and fill export variable
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            // create line with field values
            for($i = 0; $i < $field; $i++) {
                $csv_export.= '"'.$row[mysqli_fetch_field_direct($query, $i)->name].'",'.PHP_EOL;
            }
        }

        // Export the data and prompt a csv file for download
        header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$csv_filename."");
        echo($csv_export);
    }
}
?>
```

Удалить коде перед функцией `export_csv()`, содержащий html-код.
А также, в файле

> D:\DepOnline\funcs\funcs_admin.php

закомментировать `include_once('D:\/!sys_func.php');`